# neo4j select nodes that have at least n relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to build a cypher query that select people that live in a city and countries that those cities belong to.

this is what I have at them moment:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LiveIn]-(city:City) 
WHERE  s.name= "a" OR s.name= "b" OR ... 
MATCH (city)-[:IsIn]-(country:Country) 
RETURN city,country,person
```

but what I really want to say is :

```
"select cities that have atleast 5 of those people (p) liveIn them"
```

I'm not quite sure how to tackle this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LiveIn]->(city:City)-[:IsIn]->(country:Country)
WHERE  s.name in ["a", "b",...]
WITH city, country, count(p) as c, collect(p) as persons
WHERE c>=5
RETURN city,country,persons
```