# neo4j - find nodes with strong relationship

Tags: neo4j, querying

I have in my graph places and persons as labels, and a relationship "knows_the_place". Like:

```
(person)-[knows_the_place]->(place)
```

A person usually knows multiple places.

Now I want to find the persons with a "strong" relationship via the places (which have a lot of "places" in common), so for example I want to query all persons, that share at least 3 different places, something like this (not working!) query:

```
MATCH
(a:person)-[:knows_the_place]->(x:place)<-[:knows_the_place]-(b:person),
(a:person)-[:knows_the_place]->(y:place)<-[:knows_the_place]-(b:person),
(a:person)-[:knows_the_place]->(z:place)<-[:knows_the_place]-(b:person)
WHERE NOT x=y and y=z
RETURN a, b
```

How can I do this with neo4j Query?

**Bonus-Question:**

Instead of showing me the person which have x places in common with another person, even better would be, if I could get a order list like:

a shares 7 places with b
c shares 5 places with b
d shares 2 places with e
f shares 1 places with a
...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [neo4j select nodes that have at least n relations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376983/neo4j-select-nodes-that-have-at-least-n-relations)   **count** keyword is the key ;)

Comment: Also, small nitpick: Neo4j style is generally to have labels as CamelCase.  Here's a guide: http://nigelsmall.com/zen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
MATCH (a:person)-[:knows_the_place]->(x:place)<-[:knows_the_place]-(b:person)
WITH a, b, count(x) AS count
WHERE count >= 3
RETURN a, b, count
```

To order:

```
MATCH (a:person)-[:knows_the_place]->(x:place)<-[:knows_the_place]-(b:person)
RETURN a, b, count(x) AS count
ORDER BY count(x) DESC
```

You can also do both by adding an `ORDER BY` to the of the first query.

Keep in mind that this query is a cartesian product of `a` and `b` so it will examine every combination of `person` nodes, which may be not great performance-wise if you have a lot of `person` nodes.  Neo4j 2.3 should warn you about these sorts of queries.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! :-)
Especially helpful is the 'AS' command, which I somehow missed. This is very useful for this and other of my tasks! But I also noticed the slow performance of such a query. Is there any general way to "monitor" a neo4j-query, to know what makes it slow? Or do I just have to know, what kind of queries are expensive?

Comment: You can prepend your queries with `EXPLAIN` and/or `PROFILE`.  The `PROFILE` clause will even give a nice visual output in the web console